# Disable some extra keys on keyboard in windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a keyboard with some types of extra keys, such as multimedia (play, pause, stop ,..), turn off, and etc.
some times it's annoying with a "exit button" just right beside arrows that accidentally presses, and programs gonna close, and some other similar problems.

I'm wondering is there any solution to disable, or change the functionality of these types of keyboard keys in Windows (win7)?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for that, but maybe it's an overkill in this situation. Anyway with lines like `yourkey::return`, you can easily "disable" them.

To see which key to add in your script, you can open ahk (`right-click > open` in the tray), then go into `View > Key history and script info`. You'll have the history of the last 40 keys you used, and you can refresh it with <kbd>F5</kbd>. To see which key you want to block, just press it, then press <kbd>F5</kbd> in the AHK window.

Otherwise, you can use [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/), which actually changes directly your registry. I never tried it though, but the manual looks promising.

Comment: Well don't hesitate to validate the answer if it was useful ;)

Comment: I've founded that there are two types of these extra keys on my keyboard, first group is that they bounded with explorer to run application, and those can get disabled through registry.
The second type is the keys that i have most problem with them, that it seems they run specific combinations of keys to do a windows shortcuts.(e.g. Alt+F4 for close button).
(So what for Sleep or shutdown key??!)
It's like that AutoHotKey can eliminate Alt+F4 globally, but not for this specific key that annoying me, as there is no difference, between these two for windows.

Comment: Because it may be there any solution for it, i prefer to not close this question, however i want to thank you again, for your fast reply.
I'm thinking to going to lock this key with some glues. :/

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment. I'll edit my answer to provide more help.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I am going to explain it with more detail.
The key that i want to block, is sending this:
"Alt (Down) -> F4 (Down) -> F4 (Up) -> Alt (Up)"
i just want to disable the "Exit button" on my keyboard, not the combination of Alt+F4.
If i disable this procedure, then i would not able to close anything using Alt+F4 combination anymore.
At last i have just opened the keyboard and covered the circuit connection below the key, the solution worked!! and the key is not working now. :)

Comment: Haha, well done ;)

Comment: Yes KeyTweak is a good solution if the keyboard layout modification must be permanent. There's also Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator as an alternative to Key Tweak.