# Windows Tablets: how to reverse behavior of Volume UP/DOWN buttons?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, audio, tablet

1. I have a Windows 8 tablet
2. It is in landscape mode
3. Tablet has volume up and down buttons

**Question**
I would like to swap what volume buttons do. What now increases volume should lower it and vice versa. Can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to solve this using scan-code remapping, as explained in this answer:

- [Finding the driver that controls the volume controls](https://superuser.com/a/703876/29943)

While that user was mapping keys to no action, the same mapping capability should be able to swap the actions mapped to the two volume keys.

Microsoft's documentation has an example of swapping CAPS LOCK with LEFT CTRL.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/keyboard-and-mouse-class-drivers

Then you just need to substitute the scan codes for "volume up" and "volume down" where the example uses CAPS LOCK and LEFT CTRL.

Comment: Can't find scan codes for volume up&down keys anywhere on MS website...

Comment: @Temuri: There's a document named "Keyboard Scan Code Specification", I can't find a web page for it, when you search MS website for it the search result is a [direct download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc).  But you may want to use a tool that displays scan codes to make sure that your tablet is using the standardized values.